# Context sensitive help on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

What I want to do is,  when I place mouse pointer over any GUI component (like push button, radio buttons, etc.) and press the <kbd>F1</kbd> key, the relevant help should be shown. I was able to get mouse coords, but couldn't get the GUI element underneath it dynamically. I am using Qt 4.7.4 and Qt Creator 2.4.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in QApplication, that may be useful to you :

```
QWidget * QApplication::widgetAt ( const QPoint & point ) [static]
```

Then you should name every widget accordingly to your needs.